# Making the header/footer of a views Content Pane available in 'Allow Settings'

Tags: views, panels

Currently in views, when using a content pane, under 'Pane Settings' there is the link 'Allow Settings' which shows these options:

[image: allow settings]

However, I would like to allow the header and footer also as options to be overwritten in the panel pane. 
The reason for this, is that I need context keywords from the Panel, which are not available in the view itself.

How could I accomplish this?